# greedy backreference in python's reguar expression?

Tags: python, regex, backreference

In my case, I want to capture repeated characters in text; at the same time, at most 3 characters before and behind the repeated patterns should be captured too. For example,

| original | prefix | repeat | postfix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1aab | 1 | aa | b |
| 1aaab | 1 | aaa | b |
| 1234aaabcde | 234 | aaa | bcd |

I coined a RE string in python:

```
reobj = re.compile("(?P<prefix>.{0,3})    (?P<repeat>(?P<infix>[a-z])(?P=infix){1,})    (?P<postfix>.{0,3})", re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL)
```

but it gives such a result:

| original | prefix | repeat | postfix | is desired? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1aab | 1 | aa | b | yes |
| 1aaab | 1a | aa | b | no |
| 1234aaabcde | 234 | aaa | bcd | yes |

any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 4 capture groups, where group infix is only for capturing a single char to be repeated.

```
(?P<prefix>.{0,3}?)(?P<repeat>(?P<infix>[a-z])(?P=infix)+)(?P<postfix>.{0,3})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zcekGD/1)